# Как сделать так, чтобы текст был справа?

Tags: html

Надо, чтобы текст (Человек 1, город Алматы) был справа от картинки. Как это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сначала покажите свой код

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css

Comment: хм, position & float думаю тебе смогут помочь.

Answer (score 3):

Если необходимо сделать слева картинку а справа текст, советую использовать следующий `html` код:

```
 <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='image'>
        <img src='/someurl'>
    </div>
    <div class='text'>
        <h2>Человек 1</h2>
        <span>Город Алматы</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

И задаем свойства `css` с помощью `flex`:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.image img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.text {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qa47t60q/)